# Facebook Business Manager System User Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-business-sdk

Every time I try to generate a system user access token I get

`An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.`

I have tried with existing apps and a new app altogether.

I am just trying to get it for adding to AdMob, it's so infuriating. I have followed the instructions to the letter multiple times.

Does anyone else have any advice on what could be going wrong? A more helpful error would be nice but that's not going to happen any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an API error at Facebook. This has now been resolved.

Comment: still not resolved !